# Xamarin Android DatePicker on XML. How do I fire a event to set time that is selected on DatePicker?

Tags: c#, datepicker, delegates, xamarin.android

I'm working on a xamarin android project using xml and I have a datepicker I want to use on the xml how do I fire the event for the datepicker below is my xml code for the DatePicker :

```
    <DatePicker
        android:id="@+id/DatePicker"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:datePickerMode="spinner"
        android:calendarViewShown="false" />
```

Activity Code :

```
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.ChangeDateTime);
        hour = DateTime.Now.Hour;
        minute = DateTime.Now.Minute;
        date = DateTime.Now;
        DateTime newDateTime;
        Vm.CurrentTime = hour.ToString() + minute.ToString();
        TimePicker.CurrentHour = (Java.Lang.Integer)DateTime.Now.Hour;
        TimePicker.CurrentMinute = (Java.Lang.Integer)DateTime.Now.Minute;

        TimePicker.TimeChanged += delegate (object sender, TimePicker.TimeChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            Vm.CurrentTime = e.HourOfDay.ToString() + e.Minute.ToString();

        };

        DatePicker.DateTime = DateTime.Now;
    }
```

I know with the TimePicker you can do a delegate for TimePicker.TimeChanged but what about for the DatePicker?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can actually just use the click event like below if you have a button on that screen :

```
SomeButton.Click += (sender, e) =>
{
    //Do your action here

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this is a bit strange on how it works (for .NET), but is as Android has been designed.

When you call de Init method of the DatePicker, you pass an IOnDateChangedListener, and on the OnSelectedDayChange function of the implemented interface you handle it.

Usually Xamarin implementations have a weak elegate to handle events if you don't set a delegate by yourself, but in this case, as the Init() method already requires this interface and it's supposed you will always call that method to initialize the date, they did not implement the weak delegate and thus there are no events.

Comment: Exactly.  Which is why it was good that I had a button I had to use.  Maybe this is a sideeffect of depracation and them wanting dev's to use the DialogFragments?

Comment: Nope, this is as I said because you (in theory) must call the Init method and then its really simple to pass "this" as the listener and implement the interface. Also if you set the listener of a class as null it's removed so they can't use the "trick" of the weak delegate by default.

Answer (score 0):

```
 private EditText  _txtdob;
 DatePickerDialog _datePickerDialog;
 protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.sign_up);
        _txtdob.Focusable = false;
        _txtdob.Click += (sender, e) =>
        {
            _datePickerDialog.Show();
        };

        _datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this, (sender, args) =>
        {
            _txtdob.Text = args.Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
            ViewModel.NewUser.DOB = args.Date.Date;
        }, 
        DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month - 1, DateTime.Now.Day);
}
```

> Here the _datePickerDialog when clicked will take the default date for today and when user selects other date it changes to the date selected by user.
>   Here  ViewModel.NewUser.DOB = args.Date.Date; line of code takes the new date selected by user where NewUser is a property in viewmodel creating a new User with UserDto and DOB is the datetime property in UserDto.